# Can I recover temporary file from IPython after a crash?

Tags: ipython

I was editing a long temporary file using the IPython's magis `%edit -p` function hwne my computer crashed from hardware reasons. I have /tmp mounted to ram, so the file cannot be retrieved from there. Can I recover the content of the temporary file? I spent a few hours writing that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way but its not very easy. You can search for deleted i nodes and you can try to recover them. But the best way is to be careful and don't work in your `/tmp` directory.

Here is a good explanation:

[Unix undelete / recover deleted files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80270/unix-linux-undelete-recover-deleted-files)

Comment: Hm, if `/tmp` is on tmpfs, that does not really help, does it? I was rather interested if IPython saves its input somewhere (it save history, but not what is executed from external files, it seems). (Can I somehow tell ipython to save temporary files somewhere else but to `/tmp`?)

Comment: Oh yes you're right thats not working... hmm... then no change... its some space on your RAM. That is definitely overwritten when you reboot your system.